# Bevel doesn't look right

Tags: bevel

Beveling used to work as one might expect, but something changed and now the bevel is funky.

I would like to see a smooth arc of 90 degrees.  Instead, the arc appears to go about 20-25 degrees before changing abruptly.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you you apply object transformation. If you resized the object, the modifiers will still be subject to warped dimensions.